# Children manipulation at SAX Parsing

Tags: java, parsing, sax, children, element

Assuming i got an XML file which im SAX parsing(to Java) of the following format:

```
                <RootElement>
                  <text> blabla </text>
                  <rule1 name="a">1</rule1>
                  <rule2 name="b">2</rule2>
                </RootElement>
```

How can i refer to the attribute of name in every rule ? My aim is to save to a txt file only the rules with name "a" for example.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read XML with a SAX Parser you implement a kind of ContentHandler (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html). Within your ContentHandler, the method startElement is called when the parser enters "rule1" and "rule2". One Parameter of startElement are the Attributes which is basically a map of attribute names ("name" in your example) to the correspondig values.

Some code snippet would look like:

```
// Handle XML SAX parser events.
private ContentHandler contentHandler = new ContentHandler() {
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {...}

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        cdata.setLength(0);
        if(atts == null) return;            
        // Write out attributes as new rows
        for(int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(atts.getLocalName(i) + ": " + atts.getValue(i));
        }
    }


    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {...}

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {...}

    // All other events are ignored
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {}
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {}
    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {}
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException {}
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {}
    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {}
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri) throws SAXException {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response,so in other words atts.localName(0) equals "a" and atts.localName(1) equals "b"?

Comment: no, the method startElement will be called twice by the parser. Once for the element "rule1" and a second time for "rule2".
Both calls will have one attribute in the Attributes parameter.

With atts.getLocalName(0) you get in both cases "name" which is the name of your attribute.
With atts.getValue(0) you will get "a" in the call of startElement for "rule1" and "b" for the second call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing the XML using SAX, you can check your element's *attribute* values inside the overridden `startElement()` method of your `ContentHandler` implementation (by extending [DefaultHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html)).

```
public class MySAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // .. other elements ..
        // process <rule1,2 etc.
        if (localName.startsWith("rule")) {
            String value = attributes.getValue("name");
            if (value != null && value.equals("a")) {
                // save this rule
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Reference** :*

[Parsing an XML File Using SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)